# In a <td> only display the <div> applied class but no the value

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-excel

I'm developing an application in MVC4.

In my View i'm using the following code to export all the columns from a [datatable](http://www.datatables.net/index) to excel file using the following code:

```
<button class="export" title="Export to excel" style ="top: 2.25em;right: -0.4em; "onclick="exportCsv($('#summaryTable').dataTable().fnSettings().aoColumns, $('#summaryTable').dataTable().fnGetData(), 'LocatorSummary');">Export</button>
```

The code of my one of the columns is the following one:

```
<td><div class="TMIcon"></div>@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ContractTM)</td>
```

I only want to show to the user the icon set in class (TMIcon), but when exporting to excel the idea is to export *the value inside my modelItem => item.ContractTM.*

If I use @Html.HiddenFor, the value is hide but not exported to the excel.

**Question:** How can I hide this value to the user but be able to export it to excel?

Thank you very much.

Comment: you're missing " at the end of the onclick

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake copying the code. Now all the code is copied. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
<td><div class="TMIcon"></div>@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.ContractTM, new { style = "display: none;" })</td>
```

using **LabelFor** instead DisplayFor and giving a **style**.

Thank you all